# Make VNC login as User Pi rather than ROOT

Tags: raspbian, vnc, root, user

How can I make VNC on Raspbian run as User Pi rather than Root?

I have tried to follow a few "simple" instructions on the internet but none of them give me any working results, and I eventually ended up breaking my VNC on my Raspberry Pi 2.

Comment: **Please don't say you've tried something without explaining exactly what it was.**  This just invites people to waste their time telling you to try something you've already tried -- or invites them to not bother telling you anything because of that risk.

Comment: I'm use a raspberry pi 4 and the default vnc user is pi and not root. I'm not sure if this was true back in 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my own question by installing X11VNC rather than TightVNC.

X11VNC had no troubles what so ever to run as Pi.

BONUS: I figured out how to make it autostart as well.

Autostart tutorial can be found in the following link: http://randomstuffidosometimes.blogspot.se/2015/05/x11vnc-autostart-on-raspbian-raspberry.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to repeat the instructions here.

Those given for VNC at [Raspberry Pi org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md) seem clear enough.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I end up not being able to connect.

Comment: That's a pity.  I followed the same instructions yesterday, apart from automating the session at login, and it worked for me.

Comment: tried it again, doesnt work. Still unable to connect. SSH connects just fine though. Any other ideas?

Comment: The instructions have changed since I first followed them. At the time, they led to VNC running as `root`. Three changes in the `vncboot` init script fixed it for me: the two lines referencing `pi`, and the `su - pi -c` in the start command.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the steps in that link once more, list out any/all responses from the Pi and list them here then someone might be able to tell you why you cannot connect.

I use xrdp on the Pi and connect to it via rdp from windows - it works very well and I'm replying from my pi through rdp right now.